# What is difference between LAG (Left Atrributed Grammar) and LATG (Left Attributed Translation Grammar)?

Tags: compilers, semantics, attribute-grammars

I am reading Compilers and am unable to understand difference between these two terms. I could not find any text which has clearly mentioned how they differ but these two separate terms are being used. Can someone please explain me?

Comment: Perhaps they mean the same thing. Stick to the terminology used in your class, or in one specific textbook.

Comment: Where did you find the two notions? Have you compared the respective definitions?